# Concatenating to a positional parameter in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Is there a simpler way in Postgres to concatenate to a positional parameter?

I came up with this solution:

```
to_tsquery('english', concat($1::text, ':*'))
```

And was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to achieving the same end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems ok, as long as you handle any error messages coming from syntactically incorrect queries.

One problem is that `concat` is not `STRICT`, so you will get `:*` for NULL values. It might be better to use

```
to_tsquery('english', $1 || ':*'))
```